# Find maximum and minimum of a function with constraint

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

I'm finding maximum and minimum of a function $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ subject to $g(x,y,z)=x^3+y^3-z^3=3$.

By the method of Lagrange multiplier, $\bigtriangledown f=\lambda \bigtriangledown g$ and $g=3$ give critical points. So I tried to solve these equalities, i.e.

$\quad 2x=3\lambda x^2,\quad 2y=3\lambda y^2,\quad 2z=-3\lambda z^2,\quad x^3+y^3-z^3=3$.

But it is too hard for me. Can anybody solve these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

There is already an accepted answer, but I thought I'd leave some remarks since this is sort of a curious constraint surface.  The function  $ \ f(x,y,z) \ = \ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \ $ can of course be thought of as the squared-distance from the origin to a point on the surface  $ \ x^3 + y^3 - z^3 \ = \ 3 \ $ .  Since this is an "open" surface, the function $ \ f \ $ has no absolute maximum value.  The discussion by **user112018** and **mathlove** shows that the choice of coordinate value for the location of extrema then are either zero or given by

$$  \ \lambda \ = \  \frac{2}{3x} \ = \ \frac{2}{3y} \ = \ -\frac{2}{3z} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x \ = \ y \ = \ -z \ .  $$

As **mathlove** has said, this offers eight possibilities, less one, since $ \ ( 0, 0, 0) \ $ is not on the surface.  The three remaining categories are:

**I -- two coordinates are zero**

$$  -z^3 \ = \ 3 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ (0, 0, -3^{1/3}) \ , \ y^3 \ = \ 3 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ (0, 3^{1/3}, 0) \ , \ x^3 \ = \ 3 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ (3^{1/3}, 0, 0) $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \  f \ = \ 3^{2/3} $$

for all three points.  These are found by following along each coordinate axis until it intersects the "dimple".

**II -- one coordinate is zero**

$$  y^3 \ - \ z^3 \ = \ 3 \ , \ y \ = \ -z \ \Rightarrow \ \ 2y^3  \ = \ 3 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ (0, \left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^{1/3} , -\left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^{1/3} ) \ ,$$

$$  x^3 \ - \ z^3 \ = \ 3 \ , \ x \ = \ -z  \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ ( \left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^{1/3} , 0 , -\left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^{1/3} ) \ ,$$

$$  x^3 \ + \ y^3 \ = \ 3 \ , \ x \ = \ y \ \Rightarrow \ \ 2x^3  \ = \ 3 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ (\left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^{1/3} , \left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^{1/3} , 0 ) $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \  f \ = \ 2 \cdot \left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^{2/3} \ = \ 2^{1/3} \cdot 3^{2/3} $$

for all three points. These are located along diagonals, in each of the three coordinate *planes*, meeting the "dimple" .

**III -- no coordinate is zero**

$$  x \ =  \ y \ = \ -z \ \Rightarrow \ \ 3x^3  \ = \ 3 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ (1, 1 , -1 ) \ \   \Rightarrow \ \  f \ = \ 3 \ . $$

This point lies on a "body diagonal" running to the "deepest corner of the dimple".

So, owing to the particular symmetries and anti-symmetries of this surface, the squared-distance function has three local and absolute minima [Category I] and what appear to be three additional (shallow) local minima [Category II] and a (very shallow) local maximum [Category III].

Answer (score 1):

HINT : 
$$2x=3\lambda x^2\iff x(2-3\lambda x)=0\iff x=0\ \text{or}\ 2-3\lambda x=0$$
$$2y=3\lambda y^2\iff y(2-3\lambda y)=0$$
$$2z=-3\lambda z^2\iff z(2+3\lambda z)=0$$

Comment: I tried that already but it is hard to proceed

Comment: Can you write your try?

Comment: If $x=y=0$, then $z=-3^\frac13$ and so $f=3^\frac23$.

Comment: If $x=0$ and $y=\frac2{3\lambda}$, then $z=\sqrt[3]{3-\left ( \frac2{3\lambda} \right )^3}$. I'm stuck in here.

Comment: OK, continue it. There are 8 possibilities. But some don't satisfy the condition. For example, $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$ does not satisfy the condition.

Comment: You can use $x^3+y^3-z^3=3$.